# What is likely going on in this tracert output? Specifically line 2

Tags: security, networking

Tracing route to www.google.com [24.244.4.93]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

1     3 ms     1 ms    27 ms  192.168.0.1

2     *        *        *     Request timed out.

3    12 ms    16 ms    19 ms  rc3no-tge0-11-0-29-1.cg.shawcable.net [64.59.132.109]

4    12 ms    17 ms    11 ms  24.244.4.93

Trace complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way traceroute works is by sending ICMP requests with increasing TTL, and waiting for TTL expired responses.

When a server just drops a packet without sending back TTL expired, that's where you get the timeout.

Comment: @mirvasaurus, It just means that the router that is one-hop away is not configured to send responses to TTL expiration.